# I need to insert 12spaces. It should match a particular string then go to next line with 12spaces

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file called space.txt. I am doing the string match with ath2. I need to insert a string "newdata" after 12 spaces. I tried the below command, which works, but used manual white 12 spaces. How it can be achieved in another way?

```
sed -e "/ath2/a\            newdata" space.txt
```

I need output like this

```
unix@BDC8-LX-CVZ52X2:~/12space$ cat space
ath1
ath2
            newdata
ath3
ath4
ath5
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like a homework question.

Comment: It is a requirement. I have tweaked the data to keep it simple. I am using the command to which works in a way but i don't want to go that way as it is not standard. If you have understood the question, can you please help me ?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is that?

Comment: I think you should not try to keep it too simple, as we don't really see the benefits of it. You should explain in the question why you want to do it, so that we can give a proper answer. E.g. you can easily create n spaces e.g. with `printf`, but for your example that would be more complicated then just writing spaces inside `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
sed "/ath2/a$(printf '\%12s')newdata" space
```

Comment: isn't this practically the same as my answer?

Comment: Yes - I guess you hit post first.

Comment: @Wayne: Exactly. This is what what i wanted. Thank you very much. 

sed "/ath2/a$(printf '\%12s')newdata" space this solved my issue.

Comment: @pLumo: Actual requirement is i need to insert 'SystemCgroup=true' to the toml file as am setting cgroupdriver to systemd. It requires indentation , it should match for the string 'runc.options' and go to next line with 12spaces. What Wayne has given is perfectly matching for my requirement. Thanks alot!!

Comment: which is exactly the same as my answer but 2 minutes later...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` to generate spaces:

```
sed -e '/ath2/a\'"$(printf %012s)"'newdata' "space.txt"
```